# Issues after upgrading to Ruby 2.5.1 - "Incompatible library version"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After using Homebrew to upgrade to Ruby 2.5.1, I am having issues creating my database in `pg`.

When I run `rake db:create` for the first time, the rake is aborted with an error like:

```
rake db:create 
rake aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /Users/jp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.bundle
/Users/jp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/jp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/jp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
```

I've confirmed that I have that version of Ruby running:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

I've also checked my Gemfile, and I have a recent Rails version installed (`rails (5.2.0)`).

Have not found any similar issues on Stack Overflow or elsewhere. Any idea where to begin with this one?

Comment: did you do `bundle install` after upgrading the Ruby version?

Comment: I did. `Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 76 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.`. Then I restarted the terminal.

Comment: try `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: Same error as above. `LoadError: incompatible library version`. Thank you though.

Comment: goto `/Users/jp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/` and see how many `bootsnap` versions do you see. Also try `gem list bootsnap` from project root and check the output

Comment: Looks good. `gem list` only shows one version `bootsnap (1.3.0, 1.1.7)` which is consistent with our gemfile.

Comment: `(1.3.0, 1.1.7)` are two versions, I think one of them is incompatible with your ruby version

Answer (score 1):

I just spend several hours on a very similar error, after upgrading a Ruby app from ruby 2.4 to 2.6. I'm using rbenv and bundler on MacOS Mojave.

I uninstalled about a dozen old versions of ruby and started clean. This got me past the exact error in the question.

This may be overkill, but it worked for me:

List all installed ruby versions:

```
rbenv versions
```

Uninstall all versions of Ruby.

```
rbenv uninstall 2.1
rbenv uninstall 2.1.9
etc.
```

Install needed version(s) of Ruby

```
rbenv install

bundle install
```

I tried running my app after `bundle install` and got dozens of warnings like these:

```
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.8.0
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring bootsnap-1.4.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.4.6
```

At that time, I could not run `bundle exec rake`

```
% bundle exec rake
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Running `bundle` appeared successful, but did not update Gemfile.lock, and did not fix the problem.

Finally, restoring all the gems to pristine solved the problem:

```
gem pristine --all
```

I could now run the app, rake, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a `pg` gem version problem. Use `gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0'` in your Gemfile then do the `bundle install`. This will resolve.